# Matplotlib Margins when plotting with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to set margins so all my points are visible when plotting with matplotlib but its doesn't seem to correctly add them. Below is my code and output.

I'm using IPython with the %matplotlib magic command.

Is there something that I'm doing obviously wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


d = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(range(10))*2)
a = d.plot(style = "o-")
a.set_axis_bgcolor('g') 
a.margins(.05)
```

[image: Matplotlib Output]

Comment: a.autoscale(tight=False)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

see the following documentation for set_ylim and set_xlim
http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=set_xlim

```
d = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(range(10))*2)
a = d.plot(style = "o-")
a.set_axis_bgcolor('g')
a.set_ylim([-1,19])
a.set_xlim([-1,11])
a.margins(.05)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I do this without setting x and y lims? For instance I would like to do this using categorical variables

Comment: Add this:
a.autoscale(tight=False)

Comment: Kevin, That's what I was missing. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin The solution in your comment is actually better than the one that you give in the answer. Maybe it would be worth adding there for completeness ...